# Reading single key value pairin json string

Tags: reactjs

How to render only Name in react code?

{
    "Name": "Demo",
    "Detail": [
        {
            "role": [
                "dev",
                "qa",
                "BA"
            ],
            "age": "35"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Did you try, is there any error?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you prop in curly braces:

```
const obj = { "Name": "Demo", "Detail": [ { "role": [ "dev", "qa", "BA" ], "age": "35" } ] }


// ... JSX

<div>{obj.Name}</div>
```